# Create procedure from select query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird2.5

I need to write a stored procedure in Firebird 2.5. I wrote this sql query:

```
INSERT INTO A_OBRATYKUMHIST(OBRAT, MONTH, YEAR, SECURITYUSER_ID, FIRM_ID)
select 
    sum(AO.Obrat), 11, 2010, AO.SecurityUser_ID, AO.Firm_ID
from A_OBRATYKUMHIST_TEMP AO
where
    AO.Rok = 2010
    and AO.Mesic <= 11
group by
    AO.SecurityUser_ID, AO.Firm_ID;
```

My goal is fill table with cumulative sums.

edit 1:

So I wrote this:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE A_TESTIK (
    start_year integer,
    end_year integer)
returns (
    obrat integer,
    mesic integer,
    rok integer)
as
declare variable "YEAR" integer = 2005;
declare variable "MONTH" integer = 1;
begin
    select
        sum(II.localamountwithoutvat), ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE),
            ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE)
    from IssuedInvoices II
    group by
        ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE), ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE)
    into :obrat, :mesic, :rok;
    suspend;
end^

SET TERM ; ^

/* Following GRANT statetements are generated automatically */

GRANT SELECT ON ISSUEDINVOICES TO PROCEDURE A_TESTIK;

/* Existing privileges on this procedure */

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE A_TESTIK TO SYSDBA;
```

But when I run this, I get error: `"Multiple rows in singleton select"`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Reading material: [Interbase 6.0 Language Reference](http://www.ibphoenix.com/files/60LangRef.zip) (specifically Chapter 3 Procedures and Triggers) and [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference Update](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25.html)

Comment: And if that doesn't help, please be more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: @Mihai
Useful comment

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel
I edited my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `SELECT` returns multiple rows, then you need to use `FOR SELECT ... DO ...`

Change the body of your stored procedure to:

```
FOR select
       sum(II.localamountwithoutvat), ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE),
        ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE)
   from IssuedInvoices II
   group by
       ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE), ib_decodedate_month(VatDate$DATE)
   into :obrat, :mesic, :rok
DO
   suspend;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the Firebird proc syntax :**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE name [(param1 datatype1, param2 datatype2, ...)] 
[RETURNS (param3 datatype3, param4 datatype4, ...)] 
AS BEGIN
  <body>
END;
```

The rest is up to you !

[Here is some good material about procs in Firebird](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/storedproc.htm)

Comment: If my answer served ! Mark the answer as answered ! Up_One for me !